# Warning while creating outlets for NSTableCellView

Tags: swift, osx-yosemite, xcode7, nstableview

I am having problems with this tutorial that I cannot understand:

http://www.brandpending.com/blog/2015/6/24/creating-a-custom-layout-nstablecellview-table-columns-with-a-storyboard-using-swift

This tutorial initially works fine. However, to try to better understand the differences between an XIB and a storyboard, I tried to create the custom NSTableCellView layout using an XIB. I couldn’t make it work.

I successfully followed the instructions on the web site until I got to step 4. I found I could not control-drag the text and label fields to BPTableCell.swift.

After more research, I added an Object to the Objects section of the XIB file and set its class to BPTableCell. I was then able to control-drag the controls to it and create IBOutlets. However a there was still a problem - there are now two warnings. The warnings read

```
MainMenu.xib: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Outlet 'itemField' of 'Table Cell' is connected to 'Item Field,' an invalid destination (Object may be repeated at runtime.)

MainMenu.xib: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Outlet 'itemLabel' of 'Table Cell' is connected to 'Item Label,' an invalid destination (Object may be repeated at runtime.)
```

I’ve googled these warnings but cannot find anything helpful.

Can someone please tell me what to do to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

The bindings are invalid because they connect to entries that are dynamically duplicated (so you'd have multiple objects connected to the same variable). This is not possible, hence the warning. But if you have a custom class for the view anyway you can access all objects from there. You can indeed bind subviews to vars in your cell/view subclass.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the help! Unfortunately I still don't understand.

1. With respect to the 'dynamically duplicated" concern. I understand the tableview is creating multiple TableCellViews...one for each row. However why is this a problem? It works with a StoryBoard. How is an XIB different in this respect from a StoryBoard?

2. Regarding the custom class, don't I have a custom class? I think BPTableCell is my custom class. How can I access all objects there since I am unable to bind the two cells to it without getting the warnings?

Comment: Hmm, I assumed you bound the objects to your file's owner or similar. I had done this when I got the mentioned warnings. And I could bind the field instead to my own subclass (derived from NSTableCellView). Essentially, I did the same as what is already there for the image and the textField members.

Comment: Maybe I can better explain what I have tried when I create an XIB project using the tutorial. 
 1. I have created a custom class BPTableCell. It is derived from NSTableCellView. 2. I have set BPTableCell as a custom class of the Table Cell using the Identity inspector. 3. I then tried to control-drag objects to it. Xcode would not let me do that. 4. I added BPTableCell as an object in the Objects section of the XIB. 5. I was able to control drag objects to it, but now I get the warnings. I would like to understand how to remove the warnings.